# How to specify a format a cell in an ExtJS grid?

Tags: javascript, extjs

For example, I have the following grid:

```
Value | Currency
------|---------
12.32 | EUR
14.00 | JPY
```

The Japanese Yen uses no decimals, so what I want to know if it's possible with ExtJS to specify the decimal places for each cell. In this case to show only 14 instead of 14.00 for JPY.

I've looked at [the number column](http://objis.com/formationextjs/lib/extjs-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.grid.column.Number.html) but from what I've seen there is no option for specifying a format for a cell.

How to specify a format a cell in an ExtJS grid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a column **renderer** to do that. You check the value of the currency and if it's JPY, then display the value without decimals :

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer

```
columns: [
    {
        text: "Value",
        flex: 1,
        dataIndex: 'value',
        renderer: function (value, metaData, record) {
            if (record.data.currency === 'JPY') {
                return Ext.util.Format.number(value, '0');
            }
            return value;
        }
    },
    {
        text: "currency",
        flex: 1,
        dataIndex: 'currency'
    }
]
```

Here is a working Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Xpe9V/1608/

Answer (score 2):

Although this question seems to be answered I want to point you into a completely other direction. Why not converting the value on the `model` (record) of the `store`? **The upside of this approach is that you don't have to worry about the value anywhere in your application, like filtering, showing it on a form or whatever.**

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
    {
        name: 'value',
        convert: function (value, record) {
            var returnValue = value;

            if (record.get('currency') === 'JPY') {
                returnValue = Ext.util.Format.number(value, '0');
            }

            return returnValue;
        }
    },
    'currency'
    ]
});
```

More information about fields on models and the possibilities:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.field.Field

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a custom grid cell which looks up the value in the currency cell and then perfom the formatting for the value..

something like:

```
Ext.define('xxx.view.dynamicdatagrid.CustomCurrencyValueFormatterColumn',
{
extend: 'Ext.grid.column.Column',
xtype: 'customCurrencyValueFormatterColumn',


renderer: function (value, metaData, record, row, col, store, gridView) {

   var returnValue ='';
  //look here in the record parameter for the value in the currency 
   var currency = row.data.Currency;

  //make a switch and call a custom formatter function dependend on the currency
   switch(currency){
       case 'Yen':
         returnValue = customFunction(value);
         break;
        ....
   }

 return returnValue;

},

initComponent: function () {
    var me = this;
    this.callParent();
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

You can set your column type to default by omitting the xtype field on its configuration.

In the fields attribute of your grid use the 'convert' function in order to programmatically format each value. For example:

```
var fields = [      
        {
            name: 'value', type: 'string', mapping: 'value',
            convert: function (v, record) {
               if (record.data.currency === 'JPY') {
                  // format your string here
                  // var value = ...
                  return value;
               }
            }
        },                 
    ];
```